# Loop elements opacity

Tags: javascript, css

I'm making script that fades 3 pictures out in order, but the pictures' opacity aren't changing. The if statements are reached but the pictures do not change. The first picture changes to 1 opacity on the page load, so I don't see why it wouldn't work in my function.

```
window.onload = function() { 
    document.getElementById("img1").style.opacity = 1;
    setInterval(swapPictures, 2000);
};

var swapPictures = function(){
   if(typeof swapPictures.img1v === 'undefined'){
         swapPictures.img1v = true;
}
if(typeof swapPictures.img2v === 'undefined'){
         swapPictures.img2v = false;
}
if(typeof swapPictures.img3v === 'undefined'){
         swapPictures.img3v = false;
}

if(swapPictures.img1v  && !swapPictures.img2v && !swapPictures.img3v){
         swapPictures.img1v = !swapPictures.img1v;
         swapPictures.img2v = !swapPictures.img2v;
         document.getElementById("img1").style.opacity = .4;
         document.getElementById("imgtwo").style.opactiy = 1;
}else if(!swapPictures.img1v && swapPictures.img2v && !swapPictures.img3v){
         swapPictures.img2v = !swapPictures.img2v;
         swapPictures.img3v = !swapPictures.img3v;
         document.getElementById("imgtwo").style.opacity = .4;
         document.getElementById("imgthree").style.opactiy = 1;
 }else if(!swapPictures.img1v && !swapPictures.img2v && swapPictures.img3v){
         swapPictures.img3v = !swapPictures.img3v;
         swapPictures.img1v = !swapPictures.img1v;
         document.getElementById("imgthree").style.opacity = .4;
         document.getElementById("img1").style.opactiy = 1;
 } 
};
```

Comment: Are you sure your `if` statements are working ? Did you check those ?

Comment: Yes, I used alert statements to check if they were called

Comment: In what browser did you check ?

Comment: Could you give a fiddle?

Comment: Checked with chrome. Here's the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tnDaD/263/

Comment: It's working in the fiddle.

Comment: Then why is it not appearing on multiple browsers and computers for me?

Comment: Isn't it visible to you ? All images has opacity of `.4`.

Comment: In which browser it's not working ?

Comment: Yeah, but they are supposed to change in order to an opacity of 1

Comment: It doesn't work in chrome for windows, or android, and internet explorer, and also safari for mac or iPad.

Comment: I want the first picture to fade in then fade out, then i want it to happen to the 2nd one after it is done, then to the 3rd one after the second one is done. Then I want it to start from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/tutan/2/edit)**

This is all you need:

```
var $mpPics = document.getElementsByClassName("mpPics");
var n = $mpPics.length;
var c = 0;

function fadeImg(){
  for(var i=0; i<n; i++) $mpPics[i].style.opacity = 0.4;
  $mpPics[c++%n].style.opacity = 1;
}
fadeImg(); 

setInterval(fadeImg, 2000);
```